# Как занести в БД существующий список (List)?

Tags: java

Может знает кто нибудь, как занести существующие данные в таблицу БД списком.
Пробовал таким образом пройтись по списку и ввести, но почему то не получилось

```java
String SQL = "insert into contact(value) values (?)";
stm = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
ReadExcelData red = new ReadExcelData();

List <String> lists = red.extractExcelContentByColumnIndex(0);
String id = "";

for (String e: lists) {
  lists.add(e);
  id = lists.toString();
  stm.setString(1, id);
}

stm.addBatch();

stm.executeBatch();
stm.close();
```

метод extractExcelContentByColumnIndex(0) возвращает список данных с колонки

Comment: а что происходит при запуске, как вы решили что не работает? попробуйте внести вызов `pstmt.addBatch();` внутрь цикла а так же удалить `id = lists.toString();` и переписать `stm.setString(1, e);`. Попробуйте проанализировать этот пример и сравнить со своим https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/ClientJDBC/BatchInsertsUsingJDBCPreparedStatements.htm

Comment: спасибо, исправил... в консоль выводит только, вставляет в таблицу, только последнее значение из списка почему то.

Comment: разобрался, переписал, все данные вставляет, stm.executeBatch(); поменял на stm.executeUpdate(); и  внес в цикл...

 SQL = "insert into contact(value) values (?)";

 ReadExcelData red = new ReadExcelData();

            List<String> list = red.extractExcelContentByColumnIndex(0);

            for (String value : list) {
                stm.setString(1, value);
                stm.addBatch();
                stm.executeUpdate();
            }
 stm.close();